# Should this Stack Overflow question be closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, close-reasons

I've just been looking at this question on Stack Overflow: [Why is GWT app not displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321111/why-is-gwt-app-not-displaying)

It drew my attention due to the unusually large bounty. Reading the question in more detail, I'm struck by:

- its excessive length
- the multi-Megabyte project uploaded to github

Does anyone else agree this might deserve closing? I can't help feeling the large bounty is an effort to "pay" someone to solve the bug. But equally, I'm struggling to find a close reason that fits.

Comment: Side question: is this a reasonable question to ask here? Or should I venture in to the world of chat for the first time to talk to other close-voters about it?

Comment: Flag with the "other" reason if you believe it should be closed. It seems a bit harsh after that much effort has been put in (I did not read the question though).

Comment: I thought you couldn't close a question with an active bounty.

Comment: @DuncanJones This seems to be the right place. And asking the community to close it is pointless when it has a bounty that prevents that from happening.

Comment: Well, there are code samples from areas suspected, OP shows effort and basic understanding of what happens, his problem is software related... It is long and complicated one, all right, but even if it's to broad anyone who invested his time to really answer it deserves his +500 rep. After that it might be fair to report as to broad or something.

Comment: @RogerRowland mortals can't, but moderator can cancel the bounty and close it. As for the case at hand, I don't think it should be closed. "Too complicated" is really not a valid reason to close a question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes I agree it shouldn't be closed - it's had a lot of interest and some useful progress has been made as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I guess you've hit the nail on the head. It is a complicated question, but that's not a fault. And as Molot points out, there has been effort on the part of the OP. Is there any point in leaving this meta question open for future readers or should I just delete it?

Comment: This calls for an "all those edits made this a confusing mess" close reason though. @ShaWizDowArd ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus from the comments is that the question demonstrates a sufficient level of effort and knowledge on the part of the OP. The length of the question is unusual, but that is not a problem in itself. The bounty goes some way towards addressing the increased level of effort required on the part of any future answerers.

Finally, and more crucially, questions with bounties cannot be closed except via a moderator. This is clearly not appropriate in this case so it should remain open.